# Report generation is very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, excel-2007, epplus

I have developed one application in c# 3.5 and sql server r2 2008 express version

In my database there are 10+ million rows and now i want to generate the report for the same in excel format, one row contain around 48 columns.

1. I have used Eppplus it take more than 45 Min. and data is divided into sheet
2. I used crystal report (old version) its also taking more than 45 Min for generating the sheet.

my query is very simple, fetching data from the single table only and report is also simple just values based nothing else.

if i used the latest version of crystal report, does it will solve my problem..?

Can anyone please suggest me what should i do to improve the performance.

Comment: Can you modify the database? It's not always the best solution, but you may need a new index... It might help people if you posted the query you're using and any available indexes.

Comment: You may not realise it but this question is very broad in scope. 1: don't drag all the data out in the report, apply filters or reduce the number of columns. 2: tune your select query. 3: apply indexes to the table and keep them up to date. 4: use SQL Reporting Services, it is faster to render than Crystal

Comment: To be clear: You want to import 10M rows into Excel?